# SQL: select max(value) when change columns in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Sorry if the title is confusing. I have a problem when Select from 2 table. I have 2 table like that.

Table 1: contains the column names of Table 2

```
+ Pkey | name1 | name2 +
+----------------------+
| 1    | a     | b     |
+----------------------+
| 2    | c     | b     |
```

Table 2: contains values

```
+ Pkey | a     | b     | c    +
+----------------------+------+
| 1    | 10    | 2     | 7    |
+----------------------+------+
| 2    | 12    | 4     | 8    |
+----------------------+------+
| 3    | 8     | 2     | 4    |
+----------------------+------+
| 4    | 7     | 1     | 3    |
```

I want to get the max(value) from the table 2 and add when select table 1
Example: With first row of table 1 contains 2 values : a and b. From these two values, we refer to table 2 to calculated column a - column b is [8,8,6,6]. After getting the max value of this column is 8 and add when query table 1. Keep going with the next rows

Desired table:

```
+ Pkey | name1 | name2 | Desired column    |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| 1    | a     | b     | 8                 |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| 2    | c     | b     | 5                 |
```

I have more than 10000 rows in table 1. I used function and It can not use dynamic in Function

Comment: Could (do) you also have a value of `'d'` for `[name(1/2)]` and a column `d`? What about `e`, `f`, etc? What have you tried so far to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Also, why does this have to be a function?

Comment: I created 2 tables to describe this problem. I have many rows and columns in the table. I used FUNCTION to solve but It can't use EXECUTE in FUNCTION. I lost a day but could not find a solution

Comment: Before trying to put everything in a function show us your SQL that gets the expected result

Comment: i use Funtion because i want to use name1 and name2  like the parameter. I can Query : " Select *, Funtion(name1,name2) from table 1"

Comment: *It can not use dynamic in Function* - Do you mean you can't execute dynamic SQL here?  If not, why?  You can't dynamically reference columns *without* using dynamic SQL

Comment: If you want to use Dynamic SQL you can't use a function. if the columns you need to reference are Dynamic, you need dynamic sql. Ergo, if the columns you need to reference are Dynamic you can't use a function. Final conclusion: **You can't use a function.** So, why do you *need* to use a function?

Comment: @Larnu  Seems the reason is convenience per their comment above *"i use Funtion because i want to use name1 and name2 like the parameter. I can Query : " Select *, Funtion(name1,name2) from table 1""*

Comment: But Stored Procedure have parameters as well, so that doesn't really give an answer. `EXEC StoredProc 'name1','name2';`

Comment: I solved it.Thank you so much. love all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to generate dynamic SQL:

```
-- Tables
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (
    Pkey int,
    name1 varchar(1),
    name2 varchar(1)
)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (Pkey, name1, name2)
VALUES 
    (1, 'a', 'b'),
    (2, 'c', 'b')

CREATE TABLE #Table2 (
    Pkey int,
    a int,
    b int,
    c int
)
INSERT INTO #Table2 (Pkey, a,b, c)
VALUES 
    (1, 10, 2, 7),
    (2, 12, 4, 8),
    (3, 8, 2, 4),
    (4, 7, 1, 3)

-- Statement
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = N''

SELECT @stm = @stm +
    N'UNION ALL 
    SELECT
        ' + STR(Pkey) + ' AS Pkey, 
        ''' + name1 + ''' AS name1, 
        ''' + name2 + ''' AS name2, ' +
        'PkeyMax = (SELECT MAX(' + name1 + ' - ' + name2 + ') FROM #Table2) '
FROM #Table1
SELECT @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, '')

-- Execution
EXEC (@stm)
```

Output:

```
Pkey    name1   name2   PkeyMax
1       a       b       8
2       c       b       5
```

Comment: I'd suggest `QUOTENAME` here, rather than raw string concatenation like `''' + name1 + ''' AS name1` and `MAX(' + name1 + ' - ' + name2 + ')`.

Comment: I solved it. I did not expect the first question I got so quick answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: with my SQL server and 10,000 rows (as mentioned in question) I got 'The query processor ran out of internal resources and could not produce a query plan. This is a rare event and only expected for extremely complex queries or queries that reference a very large number of tables or partitions. Please simplify the query. If you believe you have received this message in error, contact Customer Support Services for more information.'  But maybe your servers have got more power than mine

Comment: @Cato When a row in table 1 is created, there will be a column created in table 2, with a maximum of 200 columns. I do not know what the name of the column in table2 would look like, probably "V300456A", "V300085B" ... If a table is full, another table will be created. So I thought Zhorov way would be better. But this will be the experience when I Query.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the results you want, since there are few fields, makes sense to use CASE to get the ones you want (in order to avoid building dynamic SQL)

```
SELECT pkey,name1,name2,max(dif) FROM
    (SELECT t1.pkey, t1.name1, t1.name2, 
                case when t1.name1 ='a' then t2.a 
                     when t1.name1 ='b' then t2.b 
                     when t1.name1 ='c' then t2.c
                     end 
                -
                case when t1.name2 ='a' then t2.a 
                     when t1.name2 ='b' then t2.b 
                     when t1.name2 ='c' then t2.c
                     end dif


     FROM Table1 t1 , Table2 t2) IQ
     GROUP BY IQ.pkey,  IQ.name1, IQ.name2
```

Comment: This works for the 3 columns the OP has in their sample, however, they don't really only have 3 columns; the OP *forgot* to mention this anywhere other than the comments though.

Comment: There is a maximum number of columns, so I'd still try this approach, factors could be limits on length of SQL and limits on numbers of clauses in CASE statements (whatever they may be).  All of the columns would need to be added to the CASE statement